# How to lock specific rows in a table on another server using SSIS package for a specific time?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have Seed table in Server-1. From server-2 SSIS package is reading some specific rows from this seed table(Server-1) and I want to update this Seed table in the last of SSIS package execution. During this time frame I want to lock Seed table So from other Server's(3,4..10) SSIS package can not either read or update the value in Seed Table of server-1. Please help.

Can we do it in T-SQL? if possible then how to do that?

Regards,
--Raj Kumar

Comment: May be set isolation level to SERIALIZABLE?

Answer (score 0):

Serializable will be default isolation level in SSIS. so need not worry about locking the tables.